# How can I see my HTTP posts?

Tags: debugging, http, request, http-post

I'm trying to send http Post requests from a embedded device.

Is there any service I can use to send test POSTs to and see what my requests look like? Or is there any "test-webserver" I can install on my PC that dumps Http posts in a raw format?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you posting to in the first place?  If you are posting to a web service you developed then you could easily test it.  If you are posting to another service you didn't develop, then alter your code in develop to temporarily post to a mock service you develop that displays the request in its logs.

Comment: I'm posting to a webservice not developed by me. Thats why I want to see my requests. How can I implement that "mock service"? Or is there any free services displaying my requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Requestbin](http://requestb.in/)** does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that one of the best ways of doing this would be setting up an ad-hoc wireless network and then track the traffic via Wireshark or Fiddler. You can connect the phone to the shared network and then specifically "sniff" the wireless traffic (given that the PC is connected to a wired network).

Example for Windows Phone 7:
http://dennisdel.com/?p=611

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [PutsReq](http://putsreq.com). It is similar to RequestBin, but it is open source and you can also simulate responses and forward requests.